# Center a search bar in a container div that contains many other divs

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a container div, that contains many other divs, and in one of the divs, a search bar. Hence the html looks like this:

```
   <div id="header-middle">
        <div id="header-search">
            <form>
                <input type="text">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="header-middle-left">
        </div>
        <div id="header-transition">
        </div>
        <div id="header-middle-right">
        </div>
    </div>
```

the css I have for it is:

```
#header-middle{
    width: 400px;
    height: 64px;
    float: left;
}

#header-search{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;    
    margin-top: -32px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}

#header-middle-left{
    width: 241px;
    height: 64px;
    float: left;
    background-image:url('foo');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#header-transition{
    width: 19px;
    height: 64px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url('foo2');
}

#header-middle-right{
    width: 140px;
    height: 64px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url('foo3');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

the divs mainly just are there for style, they use images as backgrounds, and so theres no harm in the search bar covering them. However, I need it to be centered in the containing div, and cover small parts of the rest of them. Any help would be very appreciated. Also any advice about css in general would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't I got the question correctly, but do you want something like this : http://jsbin.com/icoyaz/1/ ?

Comment: Is that exactly what you needed? Should I put it as an answer?

Comment: Yes please! Ill select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit your CSS to achieve this, change `#header-middle` and `#header-search` to use the following code :

```
#header-middle {
    width: 400px;
    height: 64px;
    position: relative;
}

#header-search {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;    
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 22px;
}
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/icoyaz/1/).

Comment: The one thing I don't get is why -11px and -75px as opposed to -32 and -200px?

Comment: To get it in the center, `margin-left = width/2`, and `margin-top = height/2`

Comment: But width is 400 so if it's divided by 2, it would be 200 and 64/2 is 32 right?

Comment: `#header-search` : `width = 150px`, so `margin-left = -75px` and  `height: 22px` so `margin-top: -11px`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:relative` for `#header-search` to make its position relative to the container div `#header-middle`.

For centering you can use exact pixels if the width & height of the search box and the container div is static. This is not the best way but it should work. If they are dynamic than you can calculate with javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/rWNkj/

Comment: It's still not working, also shouldn't the red background on there be completely covered?

Comment: Also by not working, I should point out, that sqitching the positioning to relative moves the hole div up, showing the background of the container div for header-middle.